# Multi-module TypeSafe configuration files

Tags: java, gradle, config, typesafe

I'm currently working on a Gradle based multi-module Java project and I'm a bit confused as to how I should manage TypeSafe configuration files. Here's my project structure.

```
--rootProject
  -- module1
        -- application.conf
  -- module2
        -- application.conf
  -- etc...
```

All of the modules have some variables that are specific to each module. Most of the modules have some variables that are shared. I currently have to specify each of the shared variables in every module's application.conf. Is there a way to configure a project-wide .conf file? I know there's inheritance but adding an application.conf file to the root project didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding application.conf files to the non-shared modules and reference.conf files for shared modules. Explained here:

- [Libraries should put their defaults in a reference.conf on the
  classpath](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf)
- [Applications should provide an application.conf](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior)